# rxjs websocket 1005 error code on firefox

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs, micro-frontend

I have implemented a websocket on Angular with RxJS library which on Chrome works like charm but on FIrefox I get this error

[image]

The websocket is implemented on an Angular micro-fe and then included on the main application.
What might be the reason for the error and How can I fix it?

Thank you!